# Hover styling for non-clickable elements?

Tags: website-design, dropdown, hover, tooltips, consistency

In our system, currently we have good styling and effects for buttons, for example submit button, cancel button etc.

[image]

Now we have a different element. Let's say it is a summary tag element. Which acts as the summary information holder of a table.

But, on hover, it shows up a dropdown/tooltip with more information. Thats it, no fancy stuff. **PLEASE NOTE THAT THE TAG IS NOT CLICKABLE AND DOES NOT LEAD ANYWHERE**

So here we have 2 options.

**1. With hover having styling or faded effect. But my dilemma here is that wouldn't the user feel that it's clickable?**

[image]

**2. With no styling on hover.**

[image]

What do you think is the best option here? Is there any better/standard solution here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you already know it but the element just could look like a button if it is a button and this is not the case.

I would like to see more than the buttons, I would like to see where and in which situation you are implementing these elements. Is difficult to give you a good answer without this.

Otherwise my viewpoint you have 2 alternatives:

1. Make them light grey to looks inactive buttons.
2. Make them info icons like the examples below. About icon usability, you can read [this article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/).

**My question for you: If you make the elements look like an inactive button the user will mouse over them? Then the user will read your hover information?**

[image]
[image]

You must take care to prevent the grey inactive button look like another (less important) button like on this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, that control looks like a button, so users will expect to click it. Adding hover effects will only reinforce that expectation.

In any case, I would be wary of using hover to expose this information, for a few reasons:

- Hover is not a thing on touch devices, so anyone on a phone, tablet, or touch-notebook won't be able to access it.
- It makes it impossible (or at least very difficult) to select/copy+paste that information.
- It makes it impossible to compare the information in two of those summaries.
- It adds complexity because you need to take into account where the control is on the screen (so your tool-tip doesn't extend out of view).

For simplicity, I would probably use a more traditional disclosure control, which has a toggle to expand/collapse. If you can't (space restrictions, etc), I would at least add some other indicator which shows there is more information hidden - perhaps a `▼` arrow or `...` indicator, and make the expanded info toggle on click (to 'lock' it in place).

[image: Compact disclosure control example]

Comment: I agree with everything except the down arrow (which is the standard indicator for a selector). Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

"Faded" suggests greyed out/disabled, so is less likely to suggest clickability than "highlighted", which is what your buttons show.

However, hover styling may be appropriate to draw attention to the tooltip; possibly setting the background colouring or border of the selected summary element the same as the tool-tip to produce a visual connection between the two.

Do not use the **same** hover styling for buttons and your summary elements, as this can lead to the confusion you mention.